# Iframe Input button action to remain inside IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Okay so i got a small and quick checkout system inside an Iframe.. Users have the ability to add a promotional code to their orders and it will apply a discount - all works well.

However when you apply a discount or get the promotional code wrong it re-opens the checkout in its own window and breaks the theme/look.

This is the input button itself within

Shopping_cart.tpl

```
    <input type="submit" name="applyPromoCode" class="button-green" style="padding: 4px 20px 7px 20px!important;" value="[[Apply]]" id="applyPromoCode" />
```

Further down the same file I have delete promotional code option which also has to remain inside the iframe

```
    $(function() {
    $('#delete-promocode').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (confirm('[[Are you sure you want to remove the promotion code?]]')) {
            $("input[name='action']").val('deletePromoCode')
            $("input[name='shoppingCartForm']").click();
        }
    })
})
```

I have tried to target the input to the iframe name which is "iframep" however this didnt work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and if i can find provide any more information i will try!

Comment: Your button's id is `applyPromoCode` but your event handler is targeting id `delete-promocode`.

Comment: Ah forgot to add the only function i could find with the ID 

[code]  $applyPromoCode = SJB_Request::getVar('applyPromoCode', false);
  $action = $applyPromoCode?'applyPromoCode':$action;[/code]

Comment: Edit the question, don't post the corrected code in the comments

Comment: Sorry after you mentioned that i looked into it and found the function and made it stay within the Iframe! Consider your question an answer haha! Not great at this stackoverflow site :( thanks though man